# Apply css dynamically to a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am working on a modal and here is the html code of it. If you look at the style tag, i am basically overwriting the .model-content css class and .modal-dialog css class.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="Data.html">

<style>
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        margin: 120px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .modal-dialog {
        height: 70%;
    }
</style>

<div ng-show="Userinfo">
</div>

<div ng-show="!Userinfo">
</div>
```

There are 2 div mentioned and both are linked to `$scope.Userinfo`. I am using angular `ng-show` to show and hide both divs. 1st div is a small content. Hence I dont want to apply the above style to it. The second div has lot of contents in it. So when second div becomes visible, I want the above styles to attached to it.

Can anyone please let me know if i can assign the above style to 2nd div dynamically. Currently it is applying the above style to both the divs and the 1st div is looking very big when there is no need.

Comment: ng-class????
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: You can simply put css for second div without even ng-class. Just define a class and put those class names there

Comment: Are there no classes on the parent divs that the ng-show directive is being used on?

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by CSS. You can apply a CSS class with the style to the first modal but not to the second:

```
<style>
        .custom-modal .modal-content {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: auto;
            margin: 120px 0px 0px 0px;
        }

        .custom-modal .modal-dialog {
            height: 70%;
        }
</style>


<div ng-show="Userinfo" class="custom-modal">
</div>

<div ng-show="!Userinfo">
</div>
```